Use MUI breakpoints to achieve responsiveness JSONForms
I want to achieve something like this with JSONForms
company name md 5 location md 7
seo friendly url md 5 (full row and center)
generate button md 6 left align
reset button md 6 right align
I asked chatGPT to generate a ui schema for me.
This is what it generates for me


const uischema = {
        type: 'VerticalLayout',
        elements: [
            {
                type: 'HorizontalLayout',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'Control',
                        scope: '#/properties/companyName',
                        options: {
                            label: 'Company Name',
                            layout: { md: 5 }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'Control',
                        scope: '#/properties/location',
                        options: {
                            label: 'Location',
                            layout: { md: 7 }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'HorizontalLayout',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'Control',
                        scope: '#/properties/seoFriendlyUrl',
                        options: {
                            label: 'SEO Friendly URL',
                            layout: { md: 5 },
                            horizontalAlignment: 'center'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'HorizontalLayout',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'Control',
                        scope: '#/properties/',
                        options: {
                            label: 'Generate Button',
                            layout: { md: 6 },
                            horizontalAlignment: 'left'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'Control',
                        scope: '#/properties/',
                        options: {
                            label: 'Reset Button',
                            layout: { md: 6 },
                            horizontalAlignment: 'right'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };



This seems a perfect solutions for the problem I have. But seems like this is not working. Is JSON forms really have this layout property in options object? Or else what are the other ways to implement this easily?
